# Definition of an algebra over a noncommutative ring

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

I've tried in vain to find a definition of an algebra over a *noncommutative* ring. Does this algebraic structure not exist? In particular, does the following definition from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_(ring_theory) make sense for noncommutative $R$?

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring.   An algebra is an $R$-module $A$ together with a binary operation
>   $$ [\cdot,\cdot]: A\times A\to A $$
>   called $A$-multiplication, which satisfies the following axiom:
>   $$ [a x + b y, z] = a [x, z] + b [y, z], \quad  [z, a x + b y] = a[z, x] + b [z, y] $$
>   for all scalars $a$, $b$ in $R$ and all elements $x$, $y$, $z$ in $A$.

So, is there a common notion of an algebra over a noncommutative ring?

Comment: As usual, "correct" depends on what you want to do with the concept... There is no absolute notion of correctness of definitions.

Comment: You're right. I'll fix that.

Comment: Of course the definition does make sense. WIth that definition, though, R is not an algebra over itself in the obvious way in general... you may or may not want it to be, though.

Comment: I just asked the same. Does this definition imply that $R$ is central in $A$? If so, then I think it's not the right definition. I think a ring morphism $R \rightarrow A$ could be a "correct" definition, but I also have no idea.

Comment: @Mariano: I see. And which definition would resolve this defect?

Comment: As I said, it depends on what you want to do: there are sensible options... You can decide, for example, that an $R$-algebra is just a morphism $R\to A$ , or sort of more generally that $A$  is to be an $R$-bimodule such that multiplication decends to a morphism of $R$-bimodules $A\otimes_RA\to A$. I'm sure people can come up with other variants! 

Comment: To paraphrase my remote ancestor (Humpty Dumpty), words mean whatever you define them to mean.  But where does a definition lead?

Comment: I raised this question on [Math Stack Exchange](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21899/definition-of-an-algebra-over-a-noncommutative-ring), where there are  examples of rings which are good candidates for algebras over noncommutative rings: product rings, matrix rings, and polynomial rings.

Comment: Oops, bad link in my comment above...the Math Stack Exchange link is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850492/defining-algebras-over-noncommutative-rings).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The commutative notion of an (associative or not) algebra $A$ over a commutative ring $R$ has two natural generalization to the noncommutative setup, but the one you list with defined **left** $R$-linearity in both arguments is neither of them; in particular your multiplication does not necessarily induce a map from the tensor product, unless the image of $R$ is in the center. Most useful is the notion of an $R$-ring $A$ (or a ring $A$ over $R$), which is just a monoid in the monoidal category of $R$-bimodules: in other words the multiplication is a map $A\otimes A\to A$ which is *left* linear in first and *right* linear in the second factor. If we drop the associativity for the multiplication all works the same way, but I do not know if there is a common name (maybe descriptive like magma internal to the monoidal category of $R$-bimodules; or one may try a rare term nonassociative $R$-ring).

In the commutative case, the mutliplication is both left and right linear in each factor, what is here possible only if $R$ maps into the center of $A$. (Edit: I erased here one  additional nonsense sentence clearly written when tired ;) ). Thus the two useful concepts in the noncommutative case are $R$-rings (possibly nonassociative!) and, well, the subclass with that property: $R$ maps into $Z(A)$, deserving the full name of "algebra". There is also a notion of $R$-[coring](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coring), which is a comonoid in the monoidal category of $R$-bimodules, generalizing the notion of an $R$-coalgebra to a noncommutative ground ring.

Edit: I suggest also this [link](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/12/a_quick_algebra_quiz.html).

Comment: But, "the image of $R$" makes sense only if $A$ is unital, right?

Comment: I think that Chris' comment to Ben's answer below also applies here.

Comment: Apart from wrong phrasing about the center, I was anticipating Chris's comment  precisely with the discussion of left vs light linearity in each factor. Namely, if the scalars are in the center of $A$, then left and right linearity is interchangeable, what automatically takes care of that kind of comment. I added a John Baez's discussion in the link in the corrected edit above. 

Answer (score 14):

I would argue that this notion doesn't have one natural generalization.  One obvious one is what I would call an $R$-bimodule algebra, that is, an algebra which is an R-bimodule in such a way that left multiplication of $A$ commutes with right multiplication of $R$ and vice versa.  If you only have one of these actions, you would have an R-left or right module algebra.

On some level, you can't really expect there to be one correct generalization; which one is right depends on the context.  If you have an example, pick the definition that fits your example, and if you don't have an example, why worry?

Comment: The troublesome thing with the R-bimodule definition is that when you restrict to R a commutative algebra, it doesn't seem (at least to me)  to reproduce the usual notion of R-algebra. Specifically if R is a commutative algebra, then left modules are the same as right modules, but these are not the same as bimodules. There is no reason for the left and right module actions to be "the same".




Comment: Well, right, there's no way to make the left and right actions "the same" when the ring is not commutative.  You could require the ring to have an anti-involution and then try to do so, but that sounds pretty horrible. 

Answer (score 4):

[**Edit**: Thanks to Harry Gindi for pointing out that I'm only extending the notion of an *associative* algebra.]

Here is a somewhat "brute force" approach to define an *associative* algebra over a general ring.  Let's say that a ring $A$ with a fixed ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to A$ is *centrally generated* over $R$ (with respect to $f$) if $A$ is generated as a ring by the image of $R$ and a subset $X\subseteq A$ such that every element of the image of $R$ commutes with every element of $X$.

Then it's clear that whenever $R$ is commutative, a ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to A$ makes $A$ into an $R$-algebra if and only if $A$ is centrally generated over $R$ with respect to $f$.

Comment: There's no reason why an algebra should be a ring.  Most aren't, in fact!  

Comment: Oops, thanks for the pointer, Harry.  I usually live in "associative-land," so I immediately (and erroneously) assumed the question also lived there.

Comment: It should also be clear that I'm living in "unital-land."

Answer (score 3):

Why not just: $A$ is a ring together with a ring homomorphism $R\to A$?

Comment: The problem with that definition is that it is not a generalization of an algebra over a commutative ring because here R is mapped to Z(A).

Comment: Well, there are very interesting examples of things that people do want to be $R$-algebras in which $R$ non-central... 

Comment: But then I would call $A$ an "$R$-Ring" (I'm thinking of the comma category Rng/R) rather than an "$R$-algebra". But, again, I have no idea...

Comment: @Arminius: "... here $R$ is mapped to $Z(A)$." Why? Who decided? That does not feel natural to me at all.

Comment: @captain obvious: Well, the one who defined what an algebra over a commutative ring is decided this! Take a look at your wikipedia link: ...is a morphism $f:R \rightarrow A$ such that the image of $f$ is contained in the centre of $A$. But I think this makes sense.

Comment: Oh, it's Rasmus' link, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This is a follow-up to the answer by Zoran Skoda, applicable to the case where one requires "algebras" to be associative and have a unit.

I'd like to point out that a monoid $(A,\mu,\eta)$ internal to the monoidal category of $R$-bimodules is exactly the same thing as a *ring* $A$ along with a ring homomorphism $\eta:R\rightarrow A$. And a morphism $(A,\mu,\eta)\rightarrow (A',\mu',\eta')$ is exactly the same thing as a ring morphism $A\rightarrow A'$ that makes the triangle with $R$ commute.

In other words, this viewpoint can be greatly simplified if we just view an "algebra over $R$" as an object $\eta:R\rightarrow A$ in the category of rings *under* $R$. One can require that $\eta:R\rightarrow A$ have central image, or not, depending on one's needs.

Comment: How does this apply to a standard ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{H}$ to the quaternions? That is to say: how are you regarding $\mathbb{H}$ as a monoid in $\mathbb{C}$-bimodules?

Comment: What goes wrong if you do it in the obvious way? $\mathbb{H}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-$\mathbb{C}$-bimodule via the standard ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$. The multiplication map on it is left-$\mathbb{C}$-linear and right-$\mathbb{C}$-linear and middle-$\mathbb{C}$-linear. Perhaps I'm missing something; I'll give this another look tomorrow.

Comment: It still looks fine to me. It seems perhaps the worry is that $hch'\neq chh'$ for certain complex numbers $c$ and quaternions $h,h'$, so that the multiplication fails to be $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear on the left. But that doesn't seem to me to be a requirement for a multiplication $\mathbb{H}\otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: My sincere apologies; it was my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's not *exactly* what you want but in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2008.03.003) the authors define **Lie** algebras over noncommutative rings.

Comment: Name of this paper: [Bernstein and Retakh - Lie algebras and Lie groups over noncommutative rings](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2008.03.003).